# DDD driven solution structure

Tags: dependencies, domain-driven-design, project, solution

I am creating a project based on DDD principles. I came up with the following while reading the resources on the internet, does that make sense? In particular, parts like:

- Having `Shared.Core` project that is shared between bounded contexts
- Having separate `.Data` projects for each bounded context
- Having `Rest.API` that depends on `Shared.Core` and `FeatureX.Core` projects.

The following table shows the projects I have created and their dependencies, `->` denotes 'depends on'.

```
Rest.API -> Feature1.Core -> Feature1.Data
                          -> Shared.Core
         -> Feature2.Core -> Feature2.Data
                          -> Shared.Core
         -> Shared.Core
```

Comment: `.Data`-surfix is common for infrastructure implementation (i.e. databases), not for logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can name the folders whatever you want but it is recommended that:

- you have a module/namespace/package/directory that has no dependencies to any infrastructure or technology (like REST, SQL, NOSQL, MONGO etc) where only your business logic should stay; here live the Aggregates, Value objects, Domain services, Sagas etc. At least one for each Bounded context; let's name it the Domain layer. It may not depend on other Domain layers. It should be side-effects free, easy testable.
- you may use inside the domain layer  shared components but only if they are stateless and general purpose like datetime manipulation libraries, lists, stacks etc.
- anti-corruption layers that convert from remote models to local models. Most probable they depend on multiple Domain layers.
- other presentation, infrastructure and technology specific libraries and frameworks, IO adapters and ports should be clearly separated from other layers. May depend on the Domain layer.

So, to map to you already have:

```
Rest.API -> Feature1.Domain -> Shared.Lib
         -> Feature1.Infrastructure
         -> Feature1.ACL -> Feature1.Infrastructure
         -> Feature2.Domain -> Shared.Lib
         -> Feature2.Infrastructure
         -> Shared.Lib
```

With the following comments:

- Shared.Lib should contain only technology-agnostic, side-effects-free libraries, language constructs, utility functions etc
- Feature1.Domain should not contain logic from more than one Domain/Bounded context
- Feature1.ACL (Anti-corruption layer) can depends on the infrastructure (i.e. to store/fetch from a database or a cache) but should not contain business logic, only mapping logic, from remote objects/concepts to local objects/concepts.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but how does that map to what I've got? Domain layer should not depend on infrastructure, so I should reverse the dependency of `*.Data`, anti-corruption layer should be in `Rest.API` I assume, general shared stuff goes into `Shared.Core`.

Comment: @eddyP23 First of all, `Data` is ugly, it should be `Domain`

Comment: @eddyP23 and what means `.Core`?

Comment: So in my case I think `.Core` is what you are referring to as `Domain` and `.Data` is the infrastructure bit

Comment: I assume infrastructure can also depend on the domain, as it needs to know about the `ÌRepositories` and `Entity`'s it is dealing with

Comment: @eddyP23 yes, every layer can depend on the Domain